# Извлечение ключевых слов из вопросов

Tags: nlp

есть задача - извлекать ключевые слова из вопросительных предложений. Например: В какой категории товаров можно найти пипидастр?
Из этого предложения я хочу получить слова: категория товаров, пипидастр.
Пробовал сервис pullenti, а также модуль rutermextract для python. К сожалению, их результаты максимально не соответствуют моим понятиям ключевых слов. Есть ли ещё какие-нибудь специализированные программы для этого? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Обращайтесь в техподдержку сервиса, если что-то не работает. В остальном вопрос слишком общий.

Answer (score 1):

Сервис Pullenti прекрасно находит все эти ключевые слова, нужно только выбрать соответствующий анализатор (на demo-сайте это кнопка "Ключевые словосочетания"). Из того предложения найдётся и "пипидастр", и "категория товаров". В SDK это анализатор KeywordsAnalyzer.